# Printing words vertically

Tags: c++

So I'm just starting in C++, so I'm not familiar with the language, though I do have knowledge of C. I'm trying to print words vertically. Here is the problem given.

> Create an array of 25 strings.
>
> Use a sentinel loop that reads from cin until the array is full or the end of input is reached
>   (when the user presses Ctrl-D), whichever comes first.
>
> After the sentinel loop is over, use a for loop to move through the array.
>
> Remember not to travel farther than the last array element that was input.
>
> Print one array element (one string) followed by a newline
>
> Use a for loop to move through the characters of the string you just printed
>   print one character followed by a newline

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    char word;
    int count = 0;

    cout << "Enter a word: (press Ctrl-D to quit)";

    cin >> word;

    int array1[25];

    while (!cin.eof())
    {

        count = count + 1;
        cout << "Enter a word: (press Ctrl-D to quit)";

        cin >> word;
    } //end while

    for (word = 0; word <= array1[count]; word++)
    {

        cout << 'end1' << 'end1' << "There were " << count << "Words Entered" << 'end1';

    }

} //end main
```

Code is rough, it compiles, but when it is in an infinite loop with numbers comes out after the texts.

Comment: The code never puts anything into the array. Also, the instruction is *"Create an array of 25 strings."* not *"create an array of 25 ints"*. So I think you need to crack open that textbook and start reading.

Comment: if you are familiar with C, you should know why this will not work.
`int array1 [25];` has 25 elements only. `count can be any number > 0`, so say count is 250, `array1 [250]` - out of bounds. Also as said in the comment above this code does nothing and still causes out_of_bounds

Comment: Future bug to watch out for: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Comment: Tagging a question with extra languages increases the number of eyes on your problem, but some of those eyes are not interested in solving C++ problems and will be annoyed.

Comment: Future bug to watch out for: `'end1'` is not an `endl`. It is a multi-character [character literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal), and not properly defined in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the hell of it

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {

  string word;
  int count = 0;
  vector<string> arrayOfStrings;

  cout << "Enter a word: (press Ctrl-D to quit)";

  while(cin >> word){
    if(count < 25){
      arrayOfStrings.push_back(word);
      count = count + 1;
      cout << "Enter a word: (press Ctrl-D to quit)";
    } else {
      cout << "25 strings was entered";
      break;
    }
  }//end while

  for ( int j = 0; j < arrayOfStrings.size(); j++ ){
    cout << '\n' << '\n' << $j << "-st string entered " << arrayOfStrings[j] << '\n';
  }
}//end main
```

This code reads exactly 25 strings, remembers them, and even outputs them later.
This is just an educational example, which basically ignores memory managment
I strongly suggest not to use this in any actual code.
It took me about 5 mins to write this.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors in this code - perhaps if you are familiar with C, then quickly write a version in C and translate it to a more modern "C++ like" version. Perhaps look into `std::string` and `std::vector` to make life even easier.

`int array1[25];` needs to store strings, therefore it is of the wrong type.

The `while (!cin.eof())` loop needs to also check that it doesn't go over the bounds of the above array (i.e. at most 25 words).

The `for (word = 0; word <= array1[count]; word++)` loop that needs to loop exactly n times, where n is the number of words inputted, i.e. in the above while loop.